# How to handle action based permissions in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, security, permissions

I'm new to MVC and I would like to get suggestions on how to best handle action based permissions in my application.

I currently have some global permissions being checked at the controller level which work fine for rendering views the current user has access to, etc.

However, once the view has been rendered, I want to make decisions such as 'enable DELETE button, ONLY IF user has delete permissions for the item currently selected' At that point, those permissions are no longer Global but based on the context of the object selected.

How should I write my code to handle this type of scenario?

Comment: How are you controlling your "global permissions"? A code snippet might be handy.

Comment: I think you would want to make those decisions at the time the view is rendered, rather than after. If you try to enact security features from the page (ie browser) those can be overridden by modified client-side code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Default your Views have access to the User Object.

You can check on the View if User.IsInRole("myDeleteRole").

or

```
@if(User.IsInRole("MyDeleteRole"))
{
<input type="subtmt" value="Delete">
}
```

I don't know if this is the best way, but its what i have done in the past

I guess another way would be to write seperate Views depending on what rights a user has. that way you could do the logic on the controller and send the user to the specified view

```
if(User.IsInRole("MyDeleteRole")
{
return View("MyDeleteView", vm)
}
else
{
return View("NoDeleteView", vm)
}
```